# Running VBScript through task scheduler while computer is locked

Tags: vbscript, task, scheduler, locked

I have a script that loads an excel file from some link, and then writes some information from the excel file to a text file. I set up a task on Task Scheduler to run the script and then email the text file, and it works fine while logged on. It does not, however, run while the computer is locked.

Unfortunately, I need the task to be run in the early morning before I get to work. Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2015/02/18/help-my-scheduled-task-does-not-run.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think this is possible. This link [HERE](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/50813-can-a-script-made-to-work-if-the-computer-is-lock/) contains someone with a similar situation that was solved by making the computer "lock" via custom vbscript. However this is not the traditional "Lock" of a computer and actually just disables and removes a bunch of things... Further down they mention it being possible but it's very limited on what can happen... and making windows active is one of the limitations.